# how to get itemid in my List view using custom adapter

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have implemented one custom adapter for my list view having checkbox and text item. I can get the position through my overridden parameter. but how to get the id of my list row ?

following is code for custom adapter -

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_row, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.reminderRowTextId);
            viewHolder.reminderCheckBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxId);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final int pos = position;
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        int idRow = holder.text.getId();
        Log.i(TAG, "id of item selected-->" + idRow); <<<<<<------- IT IS GIVING SOME VALUE LIKE 2030771-------->>>
        String s = names[position];
        holder.text.setText(s);

        holder.reminderCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.reminderCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pos-->chkd" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    long longPos = (long)pos;
                    dbHelper.completeTask(longPos + 1);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pos-->un--chkd" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEXT CLICKED" + pos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ReminderModificationActivity.class);
                long longPos = (long)pos;
                intent.putExtra(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, longPos + 1);
                Log.i(TAG, "row clickd --> " + longPos);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

EDIT 1.1

```
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";                  
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";                
    public static final String KEY_IS_COMPLETE = "is_complete";
    private static final String TAG = "TasksDBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =                        
           "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                   + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                   + KEY_IS_COMPLETE + " boolean default 'false', "
                   + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                   + KEY_BODY + " text , " 
                   + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text);";
```

Please have a look at marked line. Can anyone please help me with how to get the id. Please be detailed as I m learning android.
Thanks in advance,
Ray

Comment: what's wrong with getItemId(position) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getId()` on a `TextView`, which [according to the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) returns the value associated with the `android:id` attribute.  This value is auto generated, and is probably the same as `R.id.reminderRowTextId`.

Basically, you're not actually setting a meaningful ID in your `ViewHolder` class. Just add another member variable, and store whatever you need.

To elaborate, an adapter is used to describe the size of a backing list/array, and provide a View for each element.  To do this properly, you implement `getView()` and `getItem()`.

`getItem()` takes a position, which is a parameter to `getView()`. Pass in `position` to `getItem()`, which will give you your item from SQLite.  Get that object's ID, and set a variable in `ViewHolder`.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this (may be some code) as how i can set SQLite id to my ViewHolder as a member variable. i have also included the DB creation query.

Comment: Ya i think i got this..thnx.. :)